# 返り値 tupleの XML Document の書き方が知りたいです

Tags: c#

VSCodeにて コードを書いています。

```cs
public (int hoge, int fuga) GetHogeFuga()
{
    return (0, 1);
}
```

tuple部分の XML Document return の書き方が知りたいです。

```cs
/// <summary>ほげふがを取得</sumarry>
/// <return>どうかけば良いかわかりません</return>
```

ご存知の方、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本家本元でも決定打は無く、2年前くらいを最後にまだ議論中のままで閉じていないようです。
[Proposal: multiple returns tags and name attributes in doc comments for a tuple return value #145](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/145)
[Proposal: XML doc comments for multiple results by tuple #13216](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13216)

上記議論中でもそうですが、タプルをパブリックなAPIや文書化の必要な仕様に使わない方が良い的な発言がいくつかあり、構造体やクラスを使った方が良さそうという発言とセットになっています。
[Adding Description to each Tuple object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8962033/9014308)
[Add XML documentation for named elements in ValueTuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50198342/9014308)

議論やQ&Aの中にいくつか書き方の提案があるのでそのどれかを採用してみるか、あるいは議論中の発言のように構造体やクラスに変えてみるか、のどちらかでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！構造体やクラスに変更する方法で進めます。